# Is it standard practice for plugins to add pages to wordpress using templates or shortcodes?

Tags: wordpress

I want my plugin to add new pages to the website and I wanted to know which is the best way for doing that. I've seen plugins which add their pages using shortcodes and other plugins which include their own page templates.

I was wondering which is the better way of adding public pages (NOT AN ADMIN PAGE) to Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both ways you described are valid . you can do both (by the way, shortcodes are just a different way to INCLUDE the template inside a post or page)

you did not specified what this template should do - but What I would do is include the template needed in the plugin folder structure, and then call it when needed , with `$plugin_directory = plugin_basename(__FILE__);`